# Advantage Integrating Shibboleth With ADFS

Tags: adfs, shibboleth

Can someone explain what the advantage of integrating Shibboleth with Microsoft ADFS is?  I have been researching both products and it seems like they have similar offerings.  There are many articles about using both together, but I have not been able to find a clear answer as to why you should use both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's mainly an Interoperability thing, that you can use ADFS as an IdP for Shibboleth and vice versa, that you can use identities from both "worlds", where ADFS is mainly used as the "gateway" to AD Authentication

Comment: This is certainly how we've used it. We had a requirement to implement both ADFS for some providers and Shibboleth for others, so adding Shibboleth support to our ADFS system simplified that job for us.